# Moving screenshots from one folder to another instantly

Tags: command-line, directory, automation, mv

I am hosting a gaming site and once in a while the server automatically creates a screenshot in the servers folder.

Unfortunately it is NOT possible to configure in the server settings where it puts these screenshots; it just always dumps the PNG file in the server config folder.

My folder structure is for example as follows:

```
/home/Game/Server1/
```

What I would like to achieve is that once the server creates a screenshot in 1 of these server folders (I have multiple), the operating system moves the screenshot **immediately** (it's always a `*.png` file) to the webserver folder, for example:

```
/var/www/Server1/filename.png
```

So that players can see the screenshot on the website.

Anyone any idea on how I can tackle this problem the smartest way? Please note that my ideal situation would be if the PNG file is moved immediately after creation.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into the [incron](http://inotify.aiken.cz/?section=common&page=home&lang=en) daemon. Similar to cron, but is triggered by file/directory changes. Should be available as a package for most distros.

Comment: It's available via the `incron` package in the Ubuntu *universe* repositories, see [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=incron&searchon=names).